# How to connect to my k8 app service through Python Kubernetes client?

Tags: python, api, kubernetes

### Context

I have an application which uses a service running in my kubernetes cluster.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq
...
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5672
...
```

```sh
$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
...
rabbitmq     ClusterIP   10.105.0.215   <none>        5672/TCP   25h
```

That application, has as well a client (Python) which at some point needs to connect to that service (for example, using pika). Of course, the client is running **outside the cluster**, but in a machine with a **kubectl configuration**.

I would like to design the code of the "client" module as if it would be inside the cluster (or similar):

```py
host = 'rabbitmq'
port = 5672

class AMQPClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Creates a connection with a AMQP broker"""
        self.parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=host, port=port)
        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(self.parameters)
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
```

### Issue

when I run the code I get the following error:

```sh
$ ./client_fun some_arguments
2020-09-18 09:36:31,137 - ERROR    - Address resolution failed: gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')
```

Of course, as "rabbitmq" is **not in my network** but in the **k8-cluster network**.

However, as kubernetes python client uses a proxy interface, according to this [manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls) it should be possible to access to the service using an url similar to this:

```
host = 'https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/rabbitmq/proxy'
```

Which is not working, so something else is missing.

In theory, when using kubectl, the cluster is accessed. So, maybe, there is an easy way that my application can access rabbitmq service **without using [nodeport](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport)**.

### Note the following:

- The service does not necessarily use HTTP/HTTPS protocol
- The IP of the cluster might be different, so the proxy-utl cannot be hardcoded. A kubernetes python client function should be use to get the IP and port. Similar to `kubectl cluster-info`, see at [manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-services/#manually-constructing-apiserver-proxy-urls)
- Port-forwarding to internal service might be a perfect solution, see [forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#forward-a-local-port-to-a-port-on-the-pod)

Comment: Can you run this service inside the cluster, so that it can use the Kubernetes-internal DNS and ClusterIP addressing?  You could use the Kubernetes API to create a Job that runs it, as the basis for a local launcher process.

Comment: That might be possible, and I think is the closest answer now, however, the idea of AMQP (or other services) is to be a lightweight message service. The idea of downloading and executing a container to publish the messages would be conceptually quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python client you need a python package: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python
In this package, you can find how to connect with k8s.

If you want to use k8s self API, you need the k8s token. [K8s API doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/) is useful, also you can find `kubectl` detail by use `-v 9` like: `kubectl get ns -v 9`

Comment: I am trying to develop it using the [python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). The idea would be to know wich function inside this package to use to make it possible. I could not find any function to open the socket in the cluster service.

Comment: Do you mean that you haven't found a way to load k8s config yet?@BorjaEst

Comment: Get the configuration is easy: `kubernetes.config.load_kube_config()` that loads the kubectl configuration. Now the step, is how to use the [python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) package to get the url, host & port to connect my client to the internal service (rabbitmq in this case).

Comment: You want to expose your service but don't want to use  `NodePort`? Python client is not used to exposing service or connect intern service, LB or Ingress is the right way.@BorjaEst

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not to access the rabbitmq through kubernetes API server as a proxy. It introduces a load on the kubernetes API server as well as kubernetes API server becomes a point of failure.

I would say expose rabbitmq using [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) type service. If you are not in supported cloud(AWS,Azure etc) environment then you could use [metlalb](https://metallb.universe.tf/) as a load balancer implementation.

Comment: Normally that would be the best option indeed, however, the application (in this case) creates as well the job on the cluster through the k8 API using [python client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python). It is for a RPC, the k8-job and rpc_queue are created by the client.